# Set a Delay to a WPF Viewbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewbox

I have a `Window` with a `Viewbox` in it. Based on the content of my `Viewbox` resizing the `Window` can get quite 'stuttery'. I don't need to have the `Viewbox` resize its content in realtime, it would be sufficient to update the `Viewbox` once the user is done resizing the `Window`.

I couldn't find anything about this topic on google by myself.

Is there a way to 'delay' my `Viewbox`?

edit: if not, what would be the best way to simulate this behavior?

Best i could think about was to create a grid around the viewbox, create 2 Properties for width and height, bind them to both window and grid with a twoway Binding and then set a delay in the binding, so the grid and the viewbox in it will resize after the delay, but then I would have to set a pre-defined starting size for my window due to the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Canvas` as the container for the `ViewBox`. (The direct container has to be a `Grid`, which gives the `ViewBox` a boundary to resize.)

Unlike Grid, Canvas uses absolute positioning, and it does not resize with the `Window`, so do its children.

```
<Grid x:Name="root">
    <Canvas>
        <Grid x:Name="innerGrid">
            <Viewbox>
                <Content here />
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Then you can control when to resize the `ViewBox` (by resizing its direct container).

The following code is inspired by the comments. It uses a one-time `Timer`, the timer starts when user has finished manipulating, and the resizing takes place when the timer interval elapsed.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer; //Declare it as a class member, not a local field, so it won't get GC'ed. 
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    timer.AutoReset = false; //the Elapsed event should be one-shot
    timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
    {
        //Since this is running on a background thread you need to marshal it back to the UI thread.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            innerGrid.Width = root.ActualWidth;
            innerGrid.Height = root.ActualHeight;
        }));
    };

    this.SizeChanged += (o, e) =>
    {
        //restart the time if user is still manipulating the window             
        timer.Stop(); 
        timer.Start();
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a Timer instead, that you just call `.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));` on and move the innerGrid calls there?

Comment: Sorry couldn’t get your idea. Could u explain a bit more?

Comment: Thanks. It works. while it looks definitively better than before, the content will resize once every second no matter if the user is finished or not. Using a timer, would it be possible to reset the timer to 1 sec each time the sizechanged event is triggered, so it will only be ellapsed once the size hasn't been changed for at least 1 sec?

Comment: Now I get it. @Default yes. In the SizeChanged event handler just reset the timer to 1 second, then in the timer’s Elapsed event handler, resize the ViewBox. So the resize will be take place only once - 1 second after the user has finished.

Comment: Could you provide a little sample regarding the timer? I tried using one, but it wont ellapse.